# Realm запрос на получение поля из RealmList

Tags: java, android, realm-database

Есть объект:

```
public class Contact extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String displayName;
    private RealmList<Phone> phone;
    private RealmList<Email> email;
    private RealmList<Note> notes;
    private RealmList<Address> addresses = new RealmList<Address>();
    private RealmList<IM> imAddresses;
    private Organization organization;
    private int status = -1;
    private String photo;
}
```

У меня к примеру есть номер телефона который храниться в объекте `Phone` а тот в списке `RealmList<Phone> phone`.

Объект `Phone` выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class Phone extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
    private String number;
    private String type;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Вопрос: каким образом по номеру телефона который содержиться в `Phone` в поле `private String number` я могу получить сам объект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему вам надо делать как-то [так](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries):

```
String numberToSearch = "8-800-800-80-80";
Contact contact = Realm.where(Contact.class).equalTo("phone.number", numberToSearch).findFirst();
```

Comment: я посмотрел документацию, попробовал ваш вариант,но почему то не работает.

Comment: Нашел ошибку, неправильную подавал строку numberToSearch, все работает!